# My view does not update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview, nsnumber

My ParseXML method reads the value of NSNumber, which can be incremented by a click of a button.

My ParseXML method has 240 objects, each 8 have an ID from 1 to 30.

The idea is that if i increment the NSNumber from 1 to 2, it refreshes my view and grabs the 8 objects that match the ID and displays it in my view.

That is exactly what is not doing.

```
.h

@interface FixturesController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableData *_responseDataFixtures;
    int goUp;
    NSNumber *test;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tableDataFixtures;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *roundParser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *seasonRoundString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *seasonRoundNumber;

- (IBAction)goUpByOne:(UIButton *)sender;

-(void) parseXMLFixtures:(NSNumber *) giveME;



@end


.m


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self parseXMLFixtures:@2];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    goUp = 1;
    test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:goUp];

}

 // this allows me to increment the count of NSNumber.
- (IBAction)goUpByOne:(UIButton *)sender {

    goUp++;

    test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:goUp];

    goUp = [test intValue];

}


-(void) parseXMLFixtures:(NSNumber *) giveME
{

    giveME = test;  

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"There's no going back"]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *xml = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];

    NSMutableArray *items = [xml objectForKey:@"Match"];

    NSMutableArray *newFixtureObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSNull *nullValue = [NSNull null];

    [newFixtureObjectArray insertObject:nullValue atIndex:0];
    [newFixtureObjectArray insertObject:nullValue atIndex:1];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in items) {
        FixturesObject *myFixtures = [FixturesObject fixtureFromXMLDictionary:dict];
        [newFixtureObjectArray addObject:myFixtures];
    }

    ///////

    _seasonRoundString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [giveME intValue]];
    _roundParser = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"round == %@", _seasonRoundString];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [newFixtureObjectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    _roundParser = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:filteredArray];
    [_roundParser insertObject:nullValue atIndex:0];

    NSLog(@" Objects of Fixtures in my array %@", _roundParser);

    /////

    [self setTableDataFixtures:_roundParser];
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you. I really need this to work so i can go sleep ˆˆ

Comment: Did you try `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you impleted the UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource methods yet?

The methods are:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{}
```

You can follow this [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-ios-uitableviewcontroller)